# Nested object reduce group by and sum - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, object, nested, reduce

I have a json object with data, I need to group these by name, sum the weight by name, and sum the grades. I have been trying for 2 days now. It should look like {name,weightTotal,grade{grade1total:, grade2total, grade2total}}... i looked through about 30 stack qs and tried reducing and foreach groupby and I don't understand any of it, I'm a 3rd year student doing my first internship. Need this to progress on the frontend to display these as a table. These are from  rest endpoint btw.

Data

```
"data": [
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 16,
      grade: {
        grade1: 16,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "pacific gigas",
      avgTotalWeight: 16,
      grade: {
        grade1: 16,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 13,
      grade: {
        grade1: 13,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 14,
      grade: {
        grade1: 14,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 15,
      grade: {
        grade1: 15,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
  ],
```

My code to get this json:

```
let a = [];

    for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
      if (!data[i]) {
        continue;
      }

      const {avgTotalWeight} = data[i];
      const {name} = data[i].truerun.batch.shellfish;
      const {alias} = data[i].truerun.grade_list;
      const {updatedAt} = data[i];
      const {isExist} = data[i].truerun;

      if (avgTotalWeight !== null) {
        let grade1,
          grade2,
          grade3 = 0;

        if (alias === "G1") {
          grade1 = avgTotalWeight;
        } else grade1 = 0;

        if (alias === "G2") {
          grade2 = avgTotalWeight;
        } else grade2 = 0;

        if (alias === "G3") {
          grade3 = avgTotalWeight;
        } else grade3 = 0;

        let b = {
          name: name,
          avgTotalWeight: avgTotalWeight,
          //updatedAt: updatedAt,
          //isExist: isExist,
          grade: {
            grade1: grade1,
            grade2: grade2,
            grade3: grade3,
          },
        };

        a.push(b);
      }
    }

    return a;
```

Comment: Would you add what is your expected result?

Comment: {
            "name": "france Naicin",
            "avgTotalWeight": 36,
            "grade": {
                "grade1": 16,
                "grade2": 10,
                "grade3": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "pacific gigas",
            "avgTotalWeight": 46,
            "grade": {
                "grade1": 16,
                "grade2": 10,
                "grade3": 20
            }
        },

Comment: sorry for the formatting, but just totals under different names so grouped by names, total weight of them, and total weight of each grades

Comment: How `france Naicin`'s `avgTotalWeight` is `36`. Is it not should be `58`

Comment: yea sorry there is more entries in the data I just scooped the first few objects, it should just be the total whatever the total should be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If some case `grade` key increases then you can add dynamic code so that it can work with infinite keys in `grade`. Just replace

```
isExist.grade.grade1 += grade.grade1;
isExist.grade.grade2 += grade.grade2;
isExist.grade.grade3 += grade.grade3;
```

with

```
Object.keys(isExist.grade).forEach((key) => {
  isExist.grade[key] += curr.grade[key];
});
```

```js
const obj = {
  data: [
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 16,
      grade: {
        grade1: 16,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "pacific gigas",
      avgTotalWeight: 16,
      grade: {
        grade1: 16,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 13,
      grade: {
        grade1: 13,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 14,
      grade: {
        grade1: 14,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "france Naicin",
      avgTotalWeight: 15,
      grade: {
        grade1: 15,
        grade2: 0,
        grade3: 0,
      },
    },
  ],
};

const result = obj.data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { name, avgTotalWeight, grade } = curr;
  const isExist = acc.find((o) => o.name === name);
  if (isExist) {
    isExist.weightTotal += avgTotalWeight;
    isExist.grade.grade1 += grade.grade1;
    isExist.grade.grade2 += grade.grade2;
    isExist.grade.grade3 += grade.grade3;
  } else {
    acc.push({
      name,
      weightTotal: avgTotalWeight,
      grade,
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: Added `weightTotal` of same person and individual `grade` also.

Comment: thanks thats a start, the weight is summed up correctly, the grades ar enot however, not sure why, there are grade 2 and grade 3 ones there and I'm just getting 8000 grade 1 for the first name :/

Comment: so the weight is summed correctly grouped by name, the grades are wrong unfortunatley

Comment: updating code...

Comment: updated code, Please verify Is this what you want...

Comment: it worked!! thanks so much ill be sure to study it so I understand it, thanks a million I'm not sure how to support you for this answer !

Comment: cannot thank you enough